# pjsip crash libpjsua2.so signal 11

Tags: crash, pjsip

Anybody can help to solve crash problem?

Lib works perfect, but 10% users have crashes like this.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
<unknown>

Android 7.0 3   100.0%
By device
Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte)   2
Galaxy J7 Prime (on7xelte)  1
Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte)   2   66.7%
Galaxy J7 Prime (on7xelte)  1   33.3%
Today, 7:41 AM on app version 1
Samsung Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte), 2048MB RAM, Android 7.0
Report 1 of 3

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

    backtrace:
      #00  pc 0000000000000000  <unknown>
      #01  pc 000000000012bb69  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pj_ioqueue_post_completion+92)
      #02  pc 00000000000ef6f7  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (transport_detach+58)
      #03  pc 00000000000ed967  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (transport_detach+18)
      #04  pc 00000000000ea6a3  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjmedia_stream_destroy+174)
      #05  pc 00000000000be279  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_aud_stop_stream+120)
      #06  pc 00000000000b7cbf  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (stop_media_stream+58)
      #07  pc 00000000000b9473  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_media_channel_deinit+138)
      #08  pc 00000000000b274f  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_call_on_state_changed+382)
      #09  pc 00000000000c3b3d  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (inv_set_state+144)
      #10  pc 00000000000c3f89  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (inv_handle_bye_response+68)
      #11  pc 00000000000c4423  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (inv_on_state_confirmed+62)
      #12  pc 00000000000c1f35  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (mod_inv_on_tsx_state+36)
      #13  pc 00000000000de0f7  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_dlg_on_tsx_state+78)
      #14  pc 00000000000daef7  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (tsx_set_state+190)
      #15  pc 00000000000db559  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (tsx_on_state_proceeding_uac+140)
      #16  pc 00000000000db785  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (tsx_on_state_calling+204)
      #17  pc 00000000000dca97  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_tsx_recv_msg+82)
      #18  pc 00000000000dcb0f  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (mod_tsx_layer_on_rx_response+90)
      #19  pc 00000000000d31ad  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_endpt_process_rx_data+232)
      #20  pc 00000000000d32cf  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (endpt_on_rx_msg+258)
      #21  pc 00000000000d64ed  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_tpmgr_receive_packet+748)
      #22  pc 00000000000d7eed  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (on_data_read+72)
      #23  pc 000000000012dee3  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (ioqueue_on_read_complete+94)
      #24  pc 000000000012b5ad  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (ioqueue_dispatch_read_event+292)
      #25  pc 000000000012c173  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pj_ioqueue_poll+450)
      #26  pc 00000000000d3041  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_endpt_handle_events2+90)
      #27  pc 00000000000b3b51  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_handle_events+32)
      #28  pc 00000000000b3b75  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (worker_thread+16)
      #29  pc 000000000012cab9  /data/app/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (thread_main+40)
      #30  pc 0000000000047f93  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
      #31  pc 000000000001a161  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)




Android 6.0 2   100.0%
By device
Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte)   2
Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte)   2   100.0%
Today, 7:04 AM on app version 1
Samsung Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte), 2048MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1 of 2

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

    backtrace:
      #00  pc 000000000004276c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
      #01  pc 0000000000040379  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
      #02  pc 000000000001ca9b  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
      #03  pc 0000000000019d19  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
      #04  pc 000000000001755c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
      #05  pc 0000000000138fff  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+226)
      #06  pc 0000000000133cb5  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+4)
      #07  pc 0000000000133d29  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZSt9terminatev+8)
      #08  pc 0000000000133e4d  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (__cxa_throw+120)
      #09  pc 00000000000990ed  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN2pj8EndpointC2Ev+272)
      #10  pc 000000000007240f  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN21SwigDirector_EndpointC2EP7_JNIEnv+6)
      #11  pc 00000000000893eb  /mnt/asec/com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_new_1Endpoint+22)
      #12  pc 0000000001005bd5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/mnt@asec@com.cam2cam.chat.randomize.senior.lady-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Comment: I think this problem occurs in specific scenarios. Do you know, in which case these crashes being occurred?

Comment: No. I have 45 devices and I can not repeat this at not on one of them.

Comment: have you got any solution.?

Comment: No. Already 4 PjSip specialists see the code, test it and nothing (

Comment: @TaniaKozlovska any success with this ?